# Sorting manually in dart

Tags: sorting, dart

```
void main() {
  List data = [5,4,2,7,8,3];
  List sortedData = [];


    while (data.isNotEmpty) 
    { 
        // pop out the first element 
       int tmp = data.removeLast(); 

        // while temporary stack is not empty and top 
        // of stack is greater than temp 
        while (sortedData.isNotEmpty && sortedData[sortedData.length - 1] > tmp) 
        { 
            // pop from temporary stack and push 
            // it to the input stack 
            data.addAll(sortedData.removeLast());
        } 

        // push temp in tempory of stack 
        sortedData.add(tmp); 
    } 

  print(data);
  print(sortedData);
}
```

**Uncaught Error: TypeError: 8: type 'JSInt' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable'**

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.addAll(sortedData.removeLast());` should be `data.add(sortedData.removeLast());`

Answer (score 0):

Mistake in code  -

```
data.addAll(sortedData.removeLast());
```

Here is mistake remove-

```
data.add(sortedData.removeLast());
```